# ansible-pull cannot exec unable to fork

Tags: ansible, ansible-pull

I trying to use ansible-pull to configure a RHEL 7 machine and get the following error.

```
vm-stg05 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "cmd": "/usr/bin/git clone --origin origin 'ssh:********@vm-util01:/srv/git/applications.git' /var/lib/ansible/local",
    "msg": "fatal: cannot exec '/tmp/tmpU255JD': Permission denied\nfatal: unable to fork",
    "rc": 128,
    "stderr": "fatal: cannot exec '/tmp/tmpU255JD': Permission denied\nfatal: unable to fork\n",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "fatal: cannot exec '/tmp/tmpU255JD': Permission denied",
        "fatal: unable to fork"
    ],
    "stdout": "Cloning into '/var/lib/ansible/local'...\n",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "Cloning into '/var/lib/ansible/local'..."
    ]
}
```

This is a work box and is fairly locked down so I am assuming executing anything in `/tmp` is forbidden so I tried overriding the location and did not see any difference.

My first attempt was to accept the default setting. I have to run the command with `dzdo` (which is a Centrify command similar to `sudo`) and `root` is homeless so I was not surprised it failed. What bothered me was that it was still using `/tmp`

```
$ grep _tmp $ANSIBLE_CONFIG | egrep -v "^#"
remote_tmp     = ~/.ansible/tmp
local_tmp      = ~/.ansible/tmp
```

My second attempt was to create a directory.

```
$ grep _tmp $ANSIBLE_CONFIG | egrep -v "^#"
remote_tmp     = /var/lib/ansible/tmp
local_tmp      = /var/lib/ansible/tmp

$ ls -l /var/lib/ansible
total 4
-rwxr-x--- 1 root somegroup 576 Mar 12 12:51 ansiblePull.sh
drwxrwxrwx 2 root somegroup   6 Mar 12 14:08 tmp
```

The original error message is the output of running it with `/var/lib/ansible/tmp`.

```
$ ansible-pull --version
ansible-pull 2.4.2.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/wstrater/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-pull
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Jun 11 2019, 14:33:56) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
```

I even tried it as a normal user in the `/etc/sudoers` file with and without `sudo` since this where I want to end up.

```
ls -l /var/lib/ansible/
total 4
-rwxr-x--- 1 somebody somegroup 576 Mar 12 12:51 ansiblePull.sh
drwxrwxrwx 2 somebody somegroup   6 Mar 12 14:37 tmp
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Wes.

Comment: Hello, I was also facing a similar problem removing the "noexec" flag from the /tmp directory helped.

Comment: I would be very careful about removing "noexec" from your /tmp directory. The /tmp directory is writable by all. This means if your machine is hacked they can download an executable to the /tmp directory and run it.

Comment: Facing the same problem now. Did you able to fix this @billkw?. Could you please share how you managed to do this?